# Determining the cause of an infinite loop in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, infinite-loop

I am running something in Eclipse and it is stuck (I assume infinite loop).  I know about the red stop button but is there any way to stop the eclipse program and see the exact instruction(s) and back trace where it is stuck? (Eclipse build 20130919-0819) Kepler release 1

Comment: Have you tried running it on the debugger?

Comment: try the "pause" button `||`, and then "Views(>Debug>)CallStack"..

Comment: Hi.  There are thousands of lines of code.  I am not sure exactly where it is stuck.  I stepped through once and it got stuck at a line in the "finally" phrase so I put a breakpoint there and reran (debugged) it,  It got stuck but did not stop there that time.

Comment: Hence why I create little timers in each of my methods to log when a method has been ran and how long my program spends in each of my methods.

Answer (score 1):

Debugger is your best friend here. You can look for nested loops in your code too.